# SQL - Add Unique Constraint Failure

Tags: sql, constraints, alter

Trying to alter a table in SQL Server. I want to add a unique constraint to a column called `Names` in table `ReportingItemNames`:

```
ALTER TABLE ReportingItemNames
  ADD CONSTRAINT UC_ReportingItemNames$Name UNIQUE ([ReportingItemNames,Name])
```

But I am getting this error:

> Column name 'ReportingItemNames,Name' does not exist in the target table or view

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use just the column name after unique.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
ALTER TABLE ReportingItemNames
           ADD CONSTRAINT UC_ReportingItemNames UNIQUE ([Name])
```

You can refer to [ALTER TABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) documentation for more  information.

Comment: @MathLover, can you provide a link? `w3schools` isn't so good resource.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
ALTER TABLE ReportingItemNames
    ADD CONSTRAINT UC_ReportingItemNames$Name UNIQUE ([Name])
```